# pdflatex: How to reduce width (aka uneven scale) of a character or reduce interletter space?

Tags: pdftex, microtype

I read microtype package docs, searched the Web and didn't find an example for what I am trying to achieve.

Problem statement:

I would like to do one of the following options:

1. Scale all teletype characters (texttt command and alltt environment) in such way that a character's width is 80% (reduce 20%) of its usual size, but retaining its full height; or
2. Reduce 20% of interletter space just in teletype characters (texttt command and alltt environment).

I am aware about Minimal Working Example, but I don't know how to design one in this case.

Comment: Hello! Have you considered choosing a narrower monospace font? General shrinking by 20% will destroy the legibility qualities of the font!

Comment: @tohecz Sorry for omitting the details about that. I am currently using pdflatex as compiling engine and sourcecodepro package to provide Adobe Source Code Pro as teletype font. Currently I have a technical issue which restrains the text to pdflatex, so I won't be able to switch to Lua(La)Tex, XeTex, ConTeXt, etc.

Comment: You could just us \scalebox{.8}[1]{\texttt{...}} from the graphics, graphicx or adjustbox packages.  Not sure how it would affect line breaking though.

Comment: @JohnKormylo your suggestion seems very useful and I appretiate it. However, the text which I am editing has hundreds of texttt and alltt envinronment, so using scalebox in each and every place where a teletype font is used doesn't seem to be a scalable solution. Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can reduce the letterspace with microtype (why the encoding=* is needed is one of its mysteries)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[tracking]{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareMicrotypeSet*[tracking]{ttfonts}{ family=tt*}
\SetTracking{encoding=*}{ -100 }


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\ttfamily \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

You can also change the width of glyphs (assuming a type1 font) with `ExtendFont`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pdfmapline{=cmtt10 CMTT10 ".6 ExtendFont" <cmtt10.pfb}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\ttfamily \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Combinations are possible too ...

Comment: before marking this as selected answer, could you please indicate me where can I find cmtt10/CMTT10 code mapping to cmtt10.pfb file? I have no previous experience with font file. Searching in my TeX Live 2014 distribution, I found file "/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/adobe/sourcecodepro/SourceCodePro-Regular.pfb" for my desired font.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. To extract pdfmapline, I found this file in my TeX Live 2014 distro: "/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map". For my project, I will combine both parts of this answer.

Comment: +UlrikeFischer after applying in my actual project, there was a little problem with part 2 of the answer. I am applying this in a latin written text, more specifically portuguese. Characters like a acute (á), a tilde (ã) and others are printed as a squared cross character ([x]). And even if it were a English only text, tilde (~) isn't being printed correctly (e.g. http://www.exemple.org/~someone ). I'll test a little bit more and if I find a workaround, I'll comment back here.